# Persist Provider data across multiple pages not working

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, flutter-provider

I'm using `Provider` in my flutter app, and when I go to a new page, the data provided to the `Provider` at page 1 is not accessible in page 2.

The way I understood the way `Provider` works, was that there is a central place where one stores all the data, and one can access that data anywhere in the application. So in my application, which is shown below, `ToDoListManager` is the place where all the data is stored. And if I set the data in `Page 1`, then I will be able to access that data in `Page 2`, and vice versa.

If this is not correct, then what part is wrong? And why isn't it working in my application?

Here's the code

**Page 1**

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      builder: (context) => ToDoListManager(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Cool Project'),
        ),
        body:e ToDoList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ToDoList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final toDoListManager = Provider.of<ToDoListManager>(context);

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: toDoListManager.toDoList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Details(index)));
          },
          child: Text(toDoListManager.toDoList[index]),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Page 2**

```
class Details extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;

  Details(this.index);

  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      builder: (context) => ToDoListManager(),
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Details Bro'),
          ),
          body: AppBody(index)),
    );
  }
}

class AppBody extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;

  AppBody(this.index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final toDoListManager = Provider.of<ToDoListManager>(context);
    print(toDoListManager.toDoList);

    return Text(toDoListManager.toDoList[1]);
  }
}
```

**ToDoListProvider**

```
class ToDoListManager with ChangeNotifier {
  List<String> _toDoList = ['yo', 'bro'];

  List<String> get toDoList => _toDoList;

  set toDoList(List<String> newToDoList) {
    _toDoList = newToDoList;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: [This question similar with simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148419/is-possible-update-value-cross-pages-by-using-provider-in-flutter)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Place your `ChangeNotifierProvider` above your `MaterialApp` so that is accesible from any of you `Navigator` routes.
2. Keep your `Home` widget as is but when pushing the new widget with the `Navigator` provide the original Manager.

```
onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
                return Provider<ToDoListManager>.value(
                    value: toDoListManager,
                    child: Details(index),
                );
            },
        ),
    );
},
```

With both approaches you don't need to create a new `ChangeNotifierProvider` in your details screen.

Comment: Using the approach of placing the `ChangeNotifierProvider` above the `MaterialApp`, will the entire app reload upon value change?

Comment: No, only the widgets that make use of Provider.of<ToDoListManager>(context) or Consumer<ToDoListManager>. Placing them above the MaterialApp is just a matter of scope. If you have a provided value that make sense inside a screen you could have it in an specific screen widget

Comment: Thank you! And the diff between consumer and provider, is that consumer is for a ui change such as a radio button/tab, vs a provider, which will update data and thereby  update the ui?

Comment: Simple, a Provider.of will rebuild calling the build method and a Consumer will rebuild calling its property builder https://pub.dev/packages/provider#faq

Comment: Thank you Martyns for the explanation!

Comment: I think does not need to insert `Provider<ToDoListManager>.value()`

Comment: @HuyTower You do if your Provider is not above MaterialApp. Otherwise the navigation creates a "branch" in the widget tree where that provider does not exist.

Comment: Okay, I see, I think insert `MultiProvider` above `MaterialApp` is a good idea also./